# Gulp-watch ignores files with parenthesis

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

For example I need watch this file:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){

    return watch('/Users/macbook/Documents/LKK (trunk)/src/style/main.scss')
        .pipe( gulp.start('build:style') );
});
```

if path contains parenthesis, gulp just ignoring this path,
 '/LKK\ (trunk)' and 'style/*' also not working. is there way to watch this directory without renaming?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the parenthesis:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){

    return watch('/Users/macbook/Documents/LKK \(trunk\)/src/style/main.scss')
        .pipe( gulp.start('build:style') );
})
```

Notice **\** before the ( and ).

*Disclaimer* - I have not had this issue before. But I've escaped some pretty weird stuff before so that might help.

*Advise* - As a rule of thumb I don't use spaces or symbols that may mean something in different environments. And since there is no way to know which symbols those may be I stick to underscore "**_**" for spaces. It makes things very readable and in most cases it is a safe bet.